# C++ Do objects of a class have direct access to the superclass's public variables

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assume I have two classes: Grandfather, Father. Father extends Grandfather. Grandfather has a public int variable named `a`.

If I create an object of the Father class in main does the object have direct access to public member variable `a` in Grandfather?

For example, I tried something like the following but the compiler says that `a` is inaccessible. But since `a` is public shouldn't it be directly accessible from an object of Father?

```
int main()
{
    Father father;

    cout << father.a;
}
```

Comment: Add the class declarations/definitions to your code snippet.

Comment: Is `a` a static member? Or `Father.a` should be `father.a`?

Comment: the code has been corrected

Comment: If you got an error from the compiler, you should post the EXACT compiler message, ***and*** the code to reproduce it.  (because you omitted the definitions of `Grandfather` and `Father`, we don't have critical information)

Answer (score 6):

A public member is visible to objects of **any** class, not just the child classes.

Comment: what if a were protected rather than public? Would the father object still have direct access?

Comment: Yes. In that case only child classes could access it.

Answer (score 2):

> If I create an object of the Father class in main does the object have
>   direct access to public member variable a in Grandfather?

Yes.

But that's not what you're doing here:

```
cout << father.a;
```

Here you're trying to get to the `a` member of `Father` directly from within `main`, *not* from within the subclass.

If you get an error about `a` being inaccessible with this code, then `a` isn't `public` as you presume.

Comment: what if `a` were protected rather than public? Would the `father` object still have direct access?

Comment: Yes, but that's **still** not what you're doing here.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how Father inherits from Grandfather:

```
// Inherit from Base publicly
class Father: public Grandfather
{
}; // father.a is accessible from main()

// Inherit from Base privately
class Father: private Grandfather
{
}; // father.a is NOT accessible from main()

// Inherit from Base protectedly
class Father: protected Grandfather
{
}; // father.a is NOT accessible from main()

class Father: Grandfather // Defaults to private inheritance
{
}; // father.a is NOT accessible from main()
```

Having said this, it is to be distinguished that if `a` is public in Grandfather, then it is accessible from *within* any method of Father, for any of these inheritances. Note that this is NOT what you are doing in your example - you're accessing `a` directly from main(), which can be considered *outside* of both Father and Grandfather.

Comment: It is inherited without a keyword. `class Father : Grandfather`

Comment: Private is the default behaviour, that's why you couldn't access father.a from main(). Even if the a member was public in the base class, it's private in the child class.

Comment: @navig8tr That's the reason - any method of Father *will* have access to `a`.

Comment: @navig8tr: and why couldn't you post more code as requested so we could have gotten here with less w asted time & effort?

Comment: @Matt: Right, but the an object of Father will not have access to `a`. At least not without a function in Father that can access it.

Comment: @JohnDibling: When I made the post I didn't think it was necessary. Then, by the time I was going to post the other code, Matt already provided this answer. Sorry.

Comment: @navig8tr What we both said is correct: "method of Father" = "function in Father". In object oriented languages, a "method" is a class function.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah I was just clarifying. Thanks for all your help.